# iOS: 'GPX.Waypoint' does not conform to protocol 'MKAnnotation'

Tags: ios, swift

Working through CS193P, I am stuck with this error. Why I am getting this error? 
What is missing the code?

**MKGPX.swift**

```
import MapKit

extension GPX.Waypoint: MKAnnotation
{
    var cooridnate:CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    var title:String! { return name }

    var subtitle:String! { return info }
}
```

**Waypoint class**

```
class Waypoint: Entry, Printable
    {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double

        init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
            self.latitude = latitude
            self.longitude = longitude
            super.init()
        }

        var info: String? {
            set { attributes["desc"] = newValue }
            get { return attributes["desc"] }
        }
        lazy var date: NSDate? = self.attributes["time"]?.asGpxDate

        override var description: String {
            return " ".join(["lat=\(latitude)", "lon=\(longitude)", super.description])
        }
    }
```

**MKAnnotation**

```
protocol MKAnnotation : NSObjectProtocol {

    // Center latitude and longitude of the annotation view.
    // The implementation of this property must be KVO compliant.
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }

    // Title and subtitle for use by selection UI.
    optional var title: String! { get }
    optional var subtitle: String! { get }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought but are you using Swift 1.1 or 1.2.
If you are using 1.2 Paul released the new version of Trax MapKit and Trax Segue for Swift 1.2. ->
https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Or could be you misspelled "var coordinate" in MKGPX.swift